# I am unable to debug my azure function in visual studio code getting below issue

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I am facing below issue while i am running azure function locally

No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

what this exactly means

I have created basic c# http trigger function using below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp

[image]

[image]

Azure function run for local development

Comment: Did you try running the function without debugging?

Comment: Try using `FunctionName` instead of `Function` in your attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a `dotnet-isolated` Azure function and could debug and run as expected.

**Steps followed:**

- Created a .NET isolated Http Triggered function.

**local.settings.json:**

- Make sure you have added the setting `"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"`:

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}
```

**host.json:**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

- **Packages installed in .csproj:**

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**Function.cs:**

```cs
public class HttpTriggerCSharp1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HttpTriggerCSharp1> _logger;

        public HttpTriggerCSharp1(ILogger<HttpTriggerCSharp1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("HttpTriggerCSharp1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        }
    }
```

**Program.cs:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

- **Debugging the function with F5:**

[image]

- Able to run the function successfully:

[image]

Comment: I have used same steps which are there. but only difference with my code is  I haven't used this "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true", in my code. I have given that value empty. Even I keep that value my issue not got resolved

Comment: Check if you have all the packages I have mentioned in `.csproj`

Comment: yes It's there its saying failed to verify AzureWebJobsStorage connection string specified in localsettings.json

Comment: You can keep it empty. Also make sure to add `"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"` in local.settings.json .

Comment: Yes It's there I have shared the error message above which i am getting

Comment: Got it, can you change it again to `"AzureWebJobsStorage": ""` and check if still throwing the warning.